# How to ZoomOut MapView in Smartface?

Tags: smartface.io

How to ZoomOut MapView in Smartface. I tried with below lines. But, still zooming deeper to the pin.

```
Pages.MapPage.mapHotel.zoomLevel = -5;
Pages.MapPage.mapHotel.zoomLevel = -15;
Pages.MapPage.mapHotel.zoomLevel = 15;
Pages.MapPage.mapHotel.zoomLevel = 0;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: -15, -5 and 0 will look same because the zoomLevel values are between 1-20. (http://docs.smartface.io/html/P_SMF_UI_MapView_zoomLevel.htm)

But with 15, map should zoom. Other values less then 15 should not zoom as much as 15 did. Which device do you use to test?

Comment: Hi merve, Thanks for the reply. I tried with many between 1-20. but no change in zoom. 
Even i tried to change the value in palette window. But, again the value is going back to 2 which is default.
Device is Moto-G2. Any issue regarding the device?

Comment: I tested with Lg-g2, it worked for me. Write this script (Pages.MapPage.mapHotel.zoomLevel = 0;) in MapPage's onShow function. If that doesn't work, can you try to enter a value from palette, save project and check again? By the way have you upgraded to 4.4.0 or are you still using 4.3.0?

Comment: I Just upgraded to 4.4.0. But still the same issue. Even i set the zoomLevel to 0 in both script window/palette, zoom for  map is still going in. Any more suggestions.

Comment: Can you please share your project?

Comment: Hi merve,
Below is my code. Please see.

function MapPage_Self_OnShow(e){
Pages.MapPage.mapHotel.zoomLevel = 0;
Pages.MapPage.mapHotel.centerLatitude = 36.546469;
Pages.MapPage.mapHotel.centerLongitude = 31.986703;
Pages.MapPage.mapHotel.addPin({
   id : "0",
   title : "Kahya Hotel",
   subtitle : "Alanya",
   latitude : 36.546469,
   longitude : 31.986703,
   selectedImage : "pinSelected",
   unSelectedImage : "pinUnselected",
   draggable : false,
   animate : true
});
}

Comment: Hi Viyaj, now I faced the same problem with a different device, note3. I will ask it to developers. Thanks for your report and patience:)

Comment: Hi again Vijay, now I know why your map zoom at first opening. The thing is that, when there is a pin added to the map, on Android it zooms to the area where pin exists. If you dont use any pin, then it doesn't zoom if you don't want it to. I mean, the zoom in-out confusion was because of that.

Comment: Oh. Thanks merve. will try that. But, when i should add my pin then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vijay, you can use this function :

```
function showPin() {
    Pages.Page1.mapHotel.addPin({
        id : "0",
        title : "Kahya Hotel",
        subtitle : "Alanya",
        latitude : 36.546469,
        longitude : 31.986703,
        selectedImage : "pinSelected",
        unSelectedImage : "pinUnselected",
        draggable : false,
        animate : true
    });
}
```

And call it with interval as below :

```
function Page1_Self_OnShow() {
    Pages.Page1.mapHotel.zoomLevel = 0;
    Pages.Page1.mapHotel.centerLatitude = 36.546469;
    Pages.Page1.mapHotel.centerLongitude = 31.986703;
    var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
            showPin();
        }, 5000);
}
```